# Outlook-addin not working with offline office.js downloaded from GitHub

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

**Outlook** add-in using offline `office.js` library downloaded form GitHub is not working when internet is blocked. `Office.js` library is hosted on a local server.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/@microsoft/office-js/dist/office.js"></script>
```

**Outlook** client version: `16.0.4738.1000 32-bit`
GitHub **office-js** library version: `1.1.11`

When add-in is accessed, error messages are prompted in pop-up.

```sh
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'registerEnum'   
URL:
https://localhost/node_modules/@microsoft/office-js/dist/outlook-15.04.js
```

and

```sh
Error: Unable to get property 'read' of undefined or null reference   
URL:
https://localhost/node_modules/@microsoft/office-js/dist/o15apptofilemappingtable.js
```

Analyzing network calls shows that this library internally invokes other online libraries. One such library is `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/3.5/MicrosoftAjax.js`

Is there any way that this library can be used offline for deployments where internet access is blocked?

> **Note**: When internet is enabled then Outlook add-in using this library works fine.

Comment: Just to understand this when you say offline for deployments, are you referring to local machines running the server? (Connecting to the add-in from localhost?)

Comment: @MaviDomates By offline deployment I mean that exchange server and outlook clients are connect by LAN network and there is no internet connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to whether you can use these add-ins in local-mode is yes, you can. Some Outlook add-in APIs might invoke EWS APIs which would fail in the no-internet mode, but some stuff would work. I'm not convinced this is a good idea though, because you can't really develop, distribute, update the app in a similar way compared to if it was living on a server.

Regarding why your add-in is failing on local, see this question: [MicrosoftAjax.js is not loaded successfully inside Office application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631948/microsoftajax-js-is-not-loaded-successfully-inside-office-application)

**Please copy all of the `dist` folder's contents recursively.**

Comment: I have already copied `dist` folder's contents recursively. The solution mentioned in the link won't work in this scenario as accessing any library using CDN is blocked.